# what is difference between kind="con" and kind="src " in buildpath reference

Tags: eclipse, classpath

I have a classpath in my project there is two reference kind one is src one is con. con kind  referenced jars is missing in my project. What is difference between these two reference kind and.

Here my .classpath file

```
1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2 <classpath>
3   <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
4   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
5   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
6   ....
7 </classpath>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`con` is a container such as the JRE files or the required plug-ins list. `src` is a source files folder path. There is also `output` for the output binaries and some others for required projects, variables and libraries.